# Outputting HTML code from inside R markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

In my code I am checking a condition and I'd like R markdown to show an image when that condition is TRUE. Here is what I have

````
```{r}
if (LOGICAL.Condition)
  {
     cat("<img src='http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/60/6071/B4XD100Z/posters/now-stop-and-hammer-time.jpg'>")
  }
```
````

The output of R that shows up on my HTML page is a text as bellow but I want it to be an image

```
## <img src='http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/60/6071/B4XD100Z/posters/now-stop-and-hammer-time.jpg'>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option `asis` will simply write the raw results from R into the output document (which is what you'd like). Otherwise it throws that `##` in front.

````
```{r results="asis"}
if (LOGICAL.Condition)
  {
     cat("<img src='http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/60/6071/B4XD100Z/posters/now-stop-and-hammer-time.jpg'>")
  }
```
````